# Azure Active Directory access error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am using Azure Active Directory B2C in an application. When I try to call the azure login page (which is a sign-in policy), I am prompted with the following error:

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
>   We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.
>   Correlation ID: 9e8de233-669b-4495-8678-236216359c58
>   Timestamp: 2017-02-21 13:51:35Z
>   AADB2C90068: The provided application with ID 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again.

Any suggestions on how to fix this and allow user to authenticate into the application?

Comment: Did you find it in the end, I was having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have registered under the tab Applications in the non-B2C portal. Under the "Getting Started" or "Configure" tab you will find a link called "Manage B2C settings". Clicking this will take you to the new Azure portal but logged into the B2C directory instead. Go to "Applications" and register your application there.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmhBN.png)

Comment: This is how i configured it. as far as i am aware this is the only way to configure it